# Execute array of observables in sequence based on condition

Tags: rxjs

Given an array of observables where each observable can emit EMPTY, how can I execute the next observable in the array on the condition that the previous observable returned EMPTY or stop iterating the array and return a non EMPTY value once an observable in the array has emitted the first non EMPTY value?

Answer (score 1):

Here would be one approach:

```js
const emptyVal = Symbol('empty');

const src$ = concat(
    ...arrOfObservable.map(
      obs$ => obs$.pipe(
        last(null, emptyVal)
      )
    )
  ).pipe(
    filter(v => v !== emptyVal),
    first()
  )
```

The `last()` operator will emit the last emitted value, after the source completes. If there is no *last value*(`obs$` has used `EMPTY`), it will emit `emptyVal`.

`filter(v => v !== emptyVal)` will make sure that we keep *iterating* until we get a non empty value.

With `first()`, we'd stop the *iteration* and we'd get the emitted value.

Note: this approach works if the `obs$` completes at some time, otherwise `last` won't be able to do its job.